# Set an element width based on the number of siblings from its parent in LESS without any script

Tags: html, css, less

For example,

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">Column 1</div>
    <div class="column">Column 2</div>
    <div class="column">Column 3</div>
    <div class="column">Column 4</div>
</div>
```

from the above HTML, I want to set 'column' width 25% if container div has 4 children. If it has only 2 children then 'column' width 50% wise versa.

Is there any way to do this using LESS framework. But should not use any script like javascript, jquery etc...

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Less compiler has no way to find out how many siblings the element has (unless compiled at client-side and you would anyway need to use JS for that) and hence this is not possible without using scripts.

Comment: How about flex display?

Comment: `.container{display: flex;}.column{flex:1;}`

Comment: @Aroniaina - you might want to post that as an answer, as that solution works http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/k250y184/1/

Comment: @Harry, and guys I found a solution with simple CSS3 properties to acheive this without using any table or flex properties.
Please check my new answer below.

Answer (score 5):

As @Danield say in comment, I post my idea as an answer! 
My answer is base on 2 CSS rules :

- set parent to `.container{display: flex;}`
- set children to `.column{flex:1;}`

The result is :

```css
.container
{
  border:solid 1px red;
  display:flex;
}

.column
{
  border:solid 1px blue;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column">Column 2</div>
  <div class="column">Column 3</div>
  <div class="column">Column 4</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="column">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column">Column 2</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="column">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column">Column 2</div>
  <div class="column">Column 3</div>
  <div class="column">Column 4</div>
  <div class="column">Column 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an answer for the above question. Though it is not specific to LESS framework, we can acheive it through simple CSS properties.

All the CSS properties can be used in LESS. Hence it should be applicable in LESS framework.

It is really cool! Is it. Cheers!.

**Solution:**

Here is the working fiddle.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antonysuthakarj/6wwoctbc/#&togetherjs=IgpObErozE)

Here is the code.

HTML:

```
<div class="container1">
  <div class="column">Column 1</div>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="column">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column">Column 2</div>
</div>
<div class="container3">
  <div class="column">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column">Column 2</div>
  <div class="column">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container1, .container2, .container3 {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}
.container1 .column, .container2 .column, .container3 .column {
  float: left;
}
.container1 .column {
  background: #ff0000;
}
.container2 .column {
  background: #ffff00;
}
.container3 .column {
  background: #ff00ff;
}
.container1 .column:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
  width: 100%;
}
.container2 .column:first-child:nth-last-child(2), .container2  .column:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ .column {
 width: 50%;
}
.container3 .column:first-child:nth-last-child(3), .container3 .column:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ .column {
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As said by Harry:

> Less compiler has no way to find out how many siblings the element has

But this is not a LESS problem, you can solve it with simple CSS using a common `display` value.

Look at this **[jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ldetomi/k250y184/)** that shows you how `.column` elements automatically adjust their width:

Core code is the following:

```
.container
{
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
}

.column
{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

That tells browser to treat elements as a **table** and inner **table-cells**.

Comment: Thanks Luca!. Actually I am aware of this way to set equal width using display: table or display: flex. But I am expecting some thing like based on the children elements count. Consider an example. A div has 3 children by default and the children will generated dynamically. If the parent div has 3 children then each children should have 33.33% width. If suppose the parent div has 5 children then children element width should be 20% and so on. LESS has some lighten, darken, ... and also supported for some functions more than CSS. Is there any way to do this by using functions or operators etc?

Comment: As said, CSS (and LESS too) can't know how many elements there are as children of a given one, so if you don't want to use `display:flex` or `display:table` properties that auto-adapt width without requiring percentages set, unique solution is to write a jQuery function that count elements and then assign a specific css class or directly a percentage width to each one.